# What means "is not a directory" error while redirecting output? Bash scripting

Tags: bash, ubuntu, error-handling

I'm making a script that document the system resources usage every certain interval.
But for some reason several commands give me this error:

> myscript: /path/to/my/FILE is not a directory

These lines give me this error:

Input:

```
echo -e "Date: $(date +%H:%M:%S) /Hs/Mins/Segs" "\n" >> ~/Desktop/ShutDownTest/"$ExecutionNumber"/Ram/'Ram_Attempt_'"$RamAttempt".txt
echo -e 'The 3 most RAM usage processes:' "\n" "$(top -b -o %MEM -n 1 | head -n 10 | tail -n 4)" "\n" 2>> ~/Desktop/ShutDownTest/"$Execution_Number"/Errors.txt >> ~/Desktop/ShutDownTest/"$ExecutionNumber"/Ram/'Ram_Attempt_'"$RamAttempt".txt
echo -e "RAM usage:" "\n" 2>> ~/Desktop/ShutDownTest/"$ExecutionNumber"/Errors.txt >> ~/Desktop/ShutDownTest/"$ExecutionNumber"/Ram/'Ram_Attempt_'"$RamAttempt".txt
```

PD: `$ExecutionNumber = 1` ; `$RamAttempt` is also equal to 1

I don't know why is this happening i executed all the 3 commands and redirect it to a file and all was all right.

Idk why i got this error or even what means, i mean i'm redirecting output to a file, of course that a file is not a directory, touch command also outputs the same error massage in some lines.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: What is the actual `/path/to/my/FILE`? Is it part of one of the pathnames in the script?

Comment: I think it means that this is the directory part of one of the pathnames, but there's no directory with that name.

Comment: Except when I do that, the error I get is "No such file or directory"

Comment: Put `set -x` before the lines where the error happens, so you can see what's actually being executed. That might show you what's wrong. If it doesn't, then try executing that command (the one printed by `set -x`) "by hand" and see if you get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem, it was failing because instead of make a directory named as the variable $ExecutionNumber i made a file named as $ExecutionNumber.

I didn't realized it because i was expected something like "no such file or directory".

How curious, i thought that when you specify a path to a file or directory bash only evaluates if the last name is a file or a directory, supposing all the previous names should be directories.
I'll write it down later.

Thanks for the help @Barmar and @Gordon Davisson :)